# Selected option with form::select

Tags: php, kohana

I want to make a dropdown list of an array with the method `Form::select`. The dropdown is dynamically generated so the selected item can change.

I made this code :

```
echo Form::select('nomselect', 
                  $noms_sols, 
                  $_GET['id_region'], 
                  array('onchange'=>"", 
                  'id' => 'select_sols',
                  'selected' => $systeme['nom_sol']));
```

The dropdown is working but I don't have the selected item that I want. On the last line of the code, I tried something, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to do it ? Or am I forced to use a `foreach` method ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where does "Form" class come from ? Any framework ?

Comment: @Random It comes from a framework (I forgot to tag it :S)

Comment: So what framework does it use?

Comment: @AndrewRayner It uses Kohana

Answer (score 0):

Third parameter of [Form::select](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Form#select) method is a selected item. In your case value from *$_GET['id_region']* should be also in *$noms_sols* array.

For example this should add **selected** attribute on *option* with value 2.

```
$noms_sols = array("1", "2", "3");
$id_region = $_GET['id_region']; // $id_region == "2"


echo Form::select('nomselect', 
              $noms_sols, 
              $id_region);
```